# php program download permission

Tags: php, mysql

This is a page where a boss can enable or disable the download of a file for its employee. The boss should only be able to enable files for its employee that he (the boss) can already use. The programs that the employee already has access to must be green. The problem is that all programs turn green because the SQL is listening to the ID of the boss, not the ID of the employee. Any suggestions?

```
require_once('databankverbinding.php');

if(empty($_SESSION['myusername']))
    header('location: /request/login.php');
?>

<html>
<head><title>Programs</title>
<link href="css/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['myusername'])){
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo $_SESSION['userID'];}
$user = $_SESSION['userID'];
echo $_GET['UserID'];
echo $user;

$sqlq =  "SELECT tblfile.FileID, tblfile.FileName, tblfile.FileDescription,tblfile.FileType,tblfile.FileSize,tblfile.FileDate,tblfile.FileActive, tbluser_file.User_FileID, tbluser_file.FileID, tbluser_file.UserID, tbluser_file.fldactief, tbluser.UserID, tbluser.Username, tbluser.Password, tbluser.BossID
FROM tbluser INNER JOIN (tblfile INNER JOIN tbluser_file ON tblfile.FileID = tbluser_file.FileID) ON tbluser.UserID = tbluser_file.UserID WHERE tbluser_file.UserID = '".$user."'  AND tblfile.FileActive = 1  AND tbluser_file.fldactief = 1 " ; // Alle mappen ophalen

$sql = 'SELECT UserID, username FROM tbluser';


$sql .= ' WHERE UserID = '.$_GET['UserID'];

$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$sql3 =  "SELECT tblfile.FileID, tblfile.FileName, tblfile.FileDescription,tblfile.FileType,tblfile.FileSize,tblfile.FileDate,tblfile.FileActive, tbluser_file.User_FileID, tbluser_file.FileID, tbluser_file.UserID, tbluser_file.fldactief, tbluser.UserID, tbluser.Username, tbluser.Password, tbluser.BossID
FROM tbluser INNER JOIN (tblfile INNER JOIN tbluser_file ON tblfile.FileID = tbluser_file.FileID) ON tbluser.UserID = tbluser_file.UserID WHERE tbluser_file.UserID = '".$_GET['UserID']."'  AND tblfile.FileActive = 1  AND tbluser_file.fldactief = 1 " ; // Alle mappen ophalen
$res3 = mysql_query($sql3);
$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($res3);

$res = mysql_query($sqlq);

echo '
<form action="category.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Catergory Edit/Delete:</legend>
<table>';
 echo $row['UserID'];   



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

if(($row3['fldactief']) == 0){

echo '
<tr>    
<td>'. $row['FileName'] . '</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="controluser.php?action=enable&UserID='.$_GET['UserID'].'&FileID='.$row['FileID'].'"><img class="delete" src="images/enable.png" /></a></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="controluser.php?action=disable&UserID='.$_GET['UserID'].'&FileID='.$row['FileID'].'" ><img class="delete" src="images/disable.png" /></a></td>
</tr>';}
else{
echo '
<tr>    
<td><h4 style="color:green;">'. $row['FileName'] . '</h4></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="controluser.php?action=enable&UserID='.$_GET['UserID'].'&FileID='.$row['FileID'].'"><img class="delete" src="images/enable.png" /></a></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="controluser.php?action=disable&UserID='.$_GET['UserID'].'&FileID='.$row['FileID'].'" ><img class="delete" src="images/disable.png" /></a></td>
</tr>';}
}

echo '

</table>
</fieldset>
</form>

';
?>
<a href="controluser.php">Go to Control Panel</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a lot of messy code for just a little bit of description.  This seems like it needs a bit of application design applied before we get to coding, don't you think?  What does your database look like, and does it properly represent the relationships you're trying to express?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main problem you will have is tracing down where the origin of your $_GET['UserID'] comes from in the first place. I see where you are passing it back to the page for the enabling/disabling portion, but when you are gathering it for the query it is unclear where it is coming from. Is this page being passed that variable from another page? Or is it the currently logged-in user? That would be the first step in this case, is tracing that variable since that is what is being included in the SQL queries.

As a side note I'd highly recommend you properly escape and clean your data, especially before entering it into a SQL query.